# heat rate controlling algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I`m on a project to making a temperature controller. It should have ability to maintain temperature at predefined point. That can be done with on/off method or proportional method or using PID. But my problem is how to control heating rate. That means when user enter a rate, temperature should be rising according to that. I using PIC micro controller and a SSR. The main problem is content of the oven is not same at all time. So any one can help me to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: What are your requirements for heating time and temperature accuracy? If you don't have those requirements then you might as well use an on/off controller. What do you mean that the "content of the oven is not the same"? Does your controller have any information other than the current temperature and the desired temperature?

Comment: Would it be possible to have 2 PID controllers? One which runs while the temperature is a long ways from the set point and attempts to control rate of change. The other would be set to take control when near the set temperature and would control to achieve the set temperature?

Comment: Thank for reply. Temperature accuracy ±1c. Oven is use to heat polythene. But mass of polythene is not same at every time. What do you mean by heating time? My controller does not have any other information.

Comment: Macattack, thank for your idea. But i do not know how to use PID for rate controlling. If you can give me a code example it may be very helpful for me.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming but more about feedback mechanisms.

Comment: If you're looking for an algorithmic answer, you should elaborate more on exactly the behaviour you're looking for, with an example, and probably remove the [tag:pic] and [tag:c] tags, and optionally replace them with [tag:language-agnostic] or [tag:pseudocode]. Whether that or you're just looking for some code, you should show an attempt at solving the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a PID control loop to set the PWM (Pulse Width Modulation) level for the power to the heating element.

The PID control loop itself is driven by an "error" signal, which is the difference between the target temperature and the current temperature.

The output of the control loop sets the PWM level, so it is large when the error is large and small when it is "about right".

The last time I worked on one of these, we had a state where the system "on full" for the PWM to warm up the cool system until it got into range and then used the PID loop to control the heater once it was in range (+/- 1 degree for a blood tester).  That is to say, outside of the PID control loop, we had a state machine to control system (OFF, WARMING, IN_RANGE, OVER_RANGE).  The last state, OVER_RANGE, was to handle an uncontrolled heater fault (one part of fault/risk mitigation).  If the system stayed there too long, it shut down completely (and there were other mechanisms as well in other subsystems).

I have a general implementation for PID control [loops discussed here](http://nonlinearideas.com/smooth-body-rotation-using-pid-control/).  There are other references on the web for heater based PID control systems.

If you want to control the rate at which the temperature rises, I think the *easiest* approach, without having to estimate dT/dt (which can be noisy), is to determine the rate you want and set the target temperature to equally spaced values over the time you want it to rise to that level.  For example, if you want it to rise at a rate of 10C/hour, set it to increment by 1C every 6 minutes, 0.5C every 12 minutes, etc.  Be careful...you can run into small value problems in integer math (i.e. when you try to determine the smallest increment by a divide, it comes out as less than 1, so it is 0 and you never increment).

Things you will need to investigate:

1. What are the requirements for the rise time of the system.
2. How much overshoot are you allowed in the response time.
3. How accurately do you have to control the temperature (tolerance).
4. What sensing technology (thermistor, custom electronics, etc.) will you use to measure the temperature.
5. Are you using fixed point or floating point math.
6. What kinds of safety/risk issues will you have to deal with...you are heating something after all...

Comment: I understood the original problem to be that they did not want to heat the oven "as fast as possible" and then maintain temperature, but wanted to gently heat so that dT/dt was at a desired ramp slope. Did I misread it?

Comment: You read it right...I misread that part.  But I put up a solution for it.  I think it will be easier to stair step the temperature instead of trying to wrap a control loop around the dT/dt.  If the steps are small enough, then the system **should** gradually rise.

Comment: That was basically what I was getting after, but may not have described it clearly enough -- keep nudging the setpoint up a little every so often. Easy enough to do if you have a general purpose computer running the controller, and can read the current oven temperature (at least at the beginning).

Comment: No worries, you put me back on track.  Sadly, it looks like this question got the "off topic" mark.  Hopefully they can put some code into the mix so it can be reopened.  It takes solid code and deep algorithms to get this stuff to work right.

Comment: sorry for the delay. I tried with stair step as same as NonlinearIdeas. It could be solve my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear it may help.

Answer (score 0):

So you want not only a given final T, but also to control the dT/dt? If the controller doesn't have that built in, but does have the normal maintain setpoint controls, can you program it to ramp up the *setpoint* every so often, and let it do the rest of the work (via PID or proportional controller) to maintain the instantaneous setpoint? It's been a good 30 years since I fooled with controllers, but with real programmability (C) I would think you could account for the starting T and the desired final T and ramp up the setpoint over time. Are you looking to not exceed a certain dT/dt in the process? Can you accept that the heating period (ramp up time) may vary according to the starting T and the nature of the content, or do you have to reach the final T within a certain time?

Comment: Heating period is not a problem. When a value is gave for dT/dt, controller should be maintain that rate while T reaches it setpoint value.